# Get showing application

Tags: objective-c, ios

Is there a way to get the foreground application I'm currently using?
I am developing for Cydia. 
In the class SBApplication there is nothing that I found to be useful.

Comment: your question is not clear...please write clearly and provide some details

Comment: He's asking if his background process can find the name of the app that is currently in foreground.

Comment: Yes, as said @fichek . I need to I have to get the name of the application in the foreground.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A very quick web search led me to [discover](http://iphonedevwiki.net/index.php/SBApplication) that "Starting from 3.2 one can also use `-[SpringBoard _accessibilityFrontMostApplication]` to get the front most application."

Comment: Thanks, so SBApplication *currentApplication = [[objc_getClass("SpringBoard") sharedApplication] _accessibilityFrontMostApplication]; should works?