# Find out active application or if on Springboard

Tags: ios, theos, cydia-substrate

How do you find out what current active application you are in or if you are in the springboard's homepages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do that.
There is no Public API is provided by Apple to do so.

If you are looking for Private API, please check this [**post**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8252396/how-to-determine-which-apps-are-background-and-which-app-is-foreground-on-ios-by)

Comment: @twodayslate: check this post, hope this will help : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8252396/how-to-determine-which-apps-are-background-and-which-app-is-foreground-on-ios-by

Comment: That was great. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6995035/get-showing-application was also helpful. Edit your answer and I'll mark it as best